# Telerik ReportViewer Q2 2014

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

I am trying to learn how to use the Telerik Reporting dll and i cannot find a single solid example that explains setup from start to finish for wanting to render a report that is located on an ssrs server. I am trying to set it up just like the normal windows reportviewer control( i know they're not the same). I have researched trying to set the server, report path, credentials, and so forth to simply connect and find the report to render but there is not one damn example...Can someone please share the secret to get this method working? The below code worked perfectly with the windows reportviewer control but i can't find an example for the telerik one that comes close to these properties for setup.

```
                    ServerReport serverReport = rvMain.ServerReport;

                //User Credentials
                System.Net.ICredentials credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                ReportServerCredentials rptServerCrecentials = serverReport.ReportServerCredentials;
                rptServerCrecentials.NetworkCredentials = credentials;

                serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(report.ReportServer);
                serverReport.ReportPath = report.ReportPath;
                //EnableExportFormats(report.ExportTypes);

                //Render the report
                rvMain.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: After digging around more and more, it looks like the Telerik Reporting will NOT connect to an SSRS report directly. You can't even pass it credentials to login which is a red flag. All the examples are pulling the report from a file or the solution in VS which was another red flag. So i switched it all to the standard windows reportviewer and moved on. Such a fail on Telerik to leave this out on an "upgrade" over the windows version...what a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik Reporting does not support opening SSRS reports - this is the reason why you are having troubles. It can only open reports created with the Telerik report designers.

Cheers.